# Why do the sibling elements as well as the parent element move when a transition is applied to an <a> element?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
details,
summary {
  display: block;
}
section.body-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
}
div.fixed-width {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.everything-wrapper p.desc-para {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0px 27px;
}
div.links-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 0px 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 25px;
}
.a-link {
  display: table-cell;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.the-div {
  font: 0px/0 a;
  border: coral 2px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s
}
.the-div:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  border: coral 6px solid;
}
.caption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.caption:hover {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<section class="body-wrapper">



  <div class="everything-wrapper fixed-width">
    <p class="desc-para">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <div class="links-wrapper">

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- .links-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- .everything-wrapper -->



</section>
<!-- .body-wrapper -->
```

In this SSCCE, when the `transition` is applied on `.a_link` when the mouse hovers over it (`a.a_link:hover {...}`), it moves as expected, but all of its siblings as well as its container also move. I want the siblings and the container and everything except itself to remain static/at-its-place and just this element should move on which the `transition` is applied. How can I achieve that?

Comment: In short: `.a-link { vertical-align: top } .the-div { box-sizing: border-box}` does the trick. That's because in a table cell, elements are aligned vertically to the middle by default and increasing the border width of a div in a cell, increases the height of all cells, so the misalignment occurs.

Comment: since this page is static anyway, you could make the boxes fixed, and the expansion of a single box won't move anything else. (however, this is not ideal. it's best to create dynamic web pages )

Comment: @HashemQolami ' s code needs to be simply appended to the css and it'll work, here's the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6zmr41f/)

Comment: @HashemQolami This is the best answer, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do the sibling elements as well as the parent element move when a transition is applied to an `<a>` element?

That's because changing border width of an element alters the computed `width`/`height` of that element by default.

On the other hand, elements within table cells are aligned vertically to the middle by default.

Therefore altering the border width of an element within a cell affects the width/height of that cell and the other cells and respectively the alignment of the other elements.

---

> I want the siblings and the container and everything except itself to remain static/at-its-place and just this element should move on which the transition is applied. How can I achieve that?

Well there are multiple options to achieve that, but one of the most simple ones (considering the current stylesheet) is altering the `box-sizing` of div elements and aligning the elements in table cells at the top:

```css
.a-link { vertical-align: top }
.the-div { box-sizing: border-box }
```

`box-sizing: border-box` changes the default CSS box model to calculate widths and heights of elements including borders and padding but not margin.

> **[6.1. ‘box-sizing’ property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing)**
>
> **border-box**
>   The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) on
>   this element determine the border box of the element. That is, any
>   padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn
>   inside this specified width and height.

### Putting all together

```css
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
details,
summary {
  display: block;
}
section.body-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
}
div.fixed-width {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.everything-wrapper p.desc-para {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0px 27px;
}
div.links-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 0px 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 25px;
}
.a-link {
  display: table-cell;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div.the-div {
  font: 0px/0 a;
  border: coral 2px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s
}
.the-div:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  border: coral 6px solid;
}
.caption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.caption:hover {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<section class="body-wrapper">
  <div class="everything-wrapper fixed-width">
    <p class="desc-para">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <div class="links-wrapper">

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- .links-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- .everything-wrapper -->
</section>
<!-- .body-wrapper -->
```

---

Alternatively we could give the hovered div a (inset) `box-shadow` which doesn't affect the box model unlike border. Yo might want to consider.

```css
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
details,
summary {
  display: block;
}
section.body-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
}
div.fixed-width {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.everything-wrapper p.desc-para {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0px 27px;
}
div.links-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 0px 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 25px;
}
.a-link {
  display: table-cell;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.the-div {
  font: 0px/0 a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px coral;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}
.the-div:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px coral;
}
.caption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.caption:hover {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<section class="body-wrapper">
  <div class="everything-wrapper fixed-width">
    <p class="desc-para">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

    <div class="links-wrapper">

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

      <a class="a-link" href="#">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
        <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- .links-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- .everything-wrapper -->
</section>
<!-- .body-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
div.the-div {
    padding: 4px
}

div.the-div:hover {
    padding: 0;
}
```

But transitioning both padding and border at the same isn't too smooth. Alternatively, you could structure the HTML like this:

```
<a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="div-wrap">
        <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    </div>  
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
 </a>
```

and then add this CSS:

```
 .div-wrap {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }

 .div-wrap:hover {
    border: 4px solid coral;
 }
```

Removing:

```
 .the-div:hover {
    border: coral 6px solid;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try CSS after

try this code

```
div.the-div {  font: 0px/0 a;  height: 140px;  width: 140px;  position:relative;}
div.the-div:after{
content:"";
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
border: coral 2px solid;
z-index:1;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.the-div:hover{  background-color: grey;}
.the-div:hover:after {  border: coral 6px solid;}
```

paste the above code between **.a-link** and **.caption**